# c++ uint8_t* needs to be converted to an integer

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to c++
I have function that has a return parameter an unsigned char*.  I need to convert the return parameter to an integer.
I declare my return value as:

```
int length = 3;
uint8_t *transmit = new uint8_t[length];
uint8_t *receive= new uint8_t[length];
int tmp = SpiWriteAndRead(spiHandle, transmit, receive, (length), holdLow);
```

The function prototype

```
int SpiWriteAndRead (SPI_HANDLE spiHandle, uint8_t* TxData, uint8_t* RxData, uint16_t Length, bool LeaveCsLow);
```

Question is when I get back the receive buffer I need to convert the value to an integer.
How do I convert an uint8_t* to an integer?

Comment: `receive` is a (pointer to an) array of 3 `uint8_t`. It is unclear how you want to turn that array into a single `int`

Comment: You're probably better off, to use the `htonl()` `ntohl()` function to transmit integer values over a wire.

Comment: What does the documentation for the SPI device you are talking to say about the data format?  You can't just do the conversion any old way, you have to match what your device does.

Comment: Ok, so using a debugger I can view the contents of receive.  Receive buffer holds 0x00, 0x03, 0xff which is the value 1023 in binary.  This is the value that I am expecting based on the test input.  I would like to take those three bytes convert that to an integer.   I am using an MCP3008 ADC, but don't see where this tells me how to convert the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to turn a 3 byte array into a `int` is to individually `or` the bytes into the desired type after casting and shifting.

```
int value = static_cast<int>(receive[0]) << 16 | static_cast<int>(receive[1]) << 8 | static_cast<int>(receive[2]);
```

A better solution would be to use a `length` of 4

```
int length = 4;
uint8_t *transmit = new uint8_t[length];
uint8_t *receive= new uint8_t[length];
int tmp = SpiWriteAndRead(spiHandle, transmit, receive, (length), holdLow);

int value = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(recieve);
```

Finally, consider avoiding `new`/`delete` if possible. `int` holds 4 bytes just as well as `uint8_t[4]`, no need to convert to and from so much if all you wanted was an `int` anyways.

```
uint8_t transmit[sizeof(int)];
int receive = 0;
int tmp = SpiWriteAndRead(spiHandle, &transmit, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&receive), sizeof(int), holdLow);
```